# Converting Vector in x/y form to magnitude/angle in Godot

Tags: vector, godot, gdscript

For a game that I am getting started making I have had to learn vector math to calculate forces. To convert a vector from x and y to magnitude and angle I have read that I for the angle have to use the function tan^-1(y/x). Is this correct and if so how do I implement it into godots GDscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For a game that I am getting started making I have had to learn vector math to calculate forces.

First, this isn't necessarily true. Depending on your use case, it may be most effective to use [Rigid Bodies](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/tutorials/physics/rigid_body.html) and let Godot compute the effects of forces for you.

> To convert a vector from x and y to magnitude and angle I have read that I for the angle have to use the function tan^-1(y/x).

To convert a vector from x and y to magnitude and angle, use [`Vector2.length()`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_vector2.html#class-vector2-method-length) and [`Vector2.angle()`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_vector2.html#class-vector2-method-angle).

That being said, if you want to learn vector math, do it! Godot has its [own vector math docs](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/math/vector_math.html), and I'm sure you can find plenty of other similar lessons online.
However, it is good to be aware that the engine provides much of this functionality for you.
Writing a bunch of vector math instead of just calling a bultin function will just make your code more complicated.